# Counting length of date period and number of periods

Tags: sql, sql-server

I can not show a query that isn't working. Because I simply can not even wrap my brain around how to do this. I can count number of devices and number of dates for a specific device.

I have a table containing a series of dates where we have seen a specific device. Devices are registered daily, if they were seen.

I would like to count the number of breaks in the timestamp flow. So if there is a date missing in the timestamp it should register as a new block for this device.

[image: Example data:]

Since today is the 25th of may:

- Device00 should count 3 times (3 starts [green], and 3 stops [red])
- Device58 should count 2 times (3 starts [green], and 2 stops [red])

Device58, is not counted because it was active today (25/5). if Device58 is not active tomorrow, then it should be counted. If it is active tomorrow then it should not be counted.

Devices are only counted when there is at least a calendar day between entry's in the data.

Data are collected once a day (4 am) and is not time critical.

Can this be done with a SQL query? My data set is currently 100.000 rows, so I'm hoping for an "easy" way to count these. But I can't quite figure it out.

DATA:

| Device | TimeStamp |
| --- | --- |
| Device00 | 2022-04-25 |
| Device00 | 2022-04-26 |
| Device00 | 2022-04-27 |
| Device00 | 2022-04-28 |
| Device00 | 2022-04-29 |
| Device00 | 2022-04-30 |
| Device00 | 2022-05-01 |
| Device00 | 2022-05-02 |
| Device00 | 2022-05-03 |
| Device00 | 2022-05-04 |
| Device00 | 2022-05-05 |
| Device00 | 2022-05-06 |
| Device00 | 2022-05-07 |
| Device00 | 2022-05-08 |
| Device00 | 2022-05-09 |
| Device00 | 2022-05-11 |
| Device00 | 2022-05-12 |
| Device00 | 2022-05-14 |
| Device00 | 2022-05-15 |
| Device00 | 2022-05-16 |
| Device00 | 2022-05-17 |
| Device00 | 2022-05-18 |
| Device00 | 2022-05-19 |
| Device58 | 2022-04-25 |
| Device58 | 2022-04-26 |
| Device58 | 2022-04-27 |
| Device58 | 2022-04-28 |
| Device58 | 2022-04-29 |
| Device58 | 2022-04-30 |
| Device58 | 2022-05-01 |
| Device58 | 2022-05-02 |
| Device58 | 2022-05-03 |
| Device58 | 2022-05-04 |
| Device58 | 2022-05-05 |
| Device58 | 2022-05-06 |
| Device58 | 2022-05-07 |
| Device58 | 2022-05-08 |
| Device58 | 2022-05-09 |
| Device58 | 2022-05-11 |
| Device58 | 2022-05-12 |
| Device58 | 2022-05-14 |
| Device58 | 2022-05-15 |
| Device58 | 2022-05-16 |
| Device58 | 2022-05-17 |
| Device58 | 2022-05-18 |
| Device58 | 2022-05-19 |
| Device58 | 2022-05-20 |
| Device58 | 2022-05-21 |
| Device58 | 2022-05-22 |
| Device58 | 2022-05-23 |
| Device58 | 2022-05-24 |
| Device58 | 2022-05-25 |

Expected result:

| Device | Count |
| --- | --- |
| Device00 | 3 |
| Device58 | 2 |

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551) If you want to provide sample data, do so as DDL and DML statements, or at least as well formatted tabular `text` or as a markdown table. Showing your expected results for your **consumable** sample data is also really important for making it easy for us to help you.

Comment: @JGaard can you please explain why count of Device58 is 2 instead of 3?

Comment: @JGaard i do curious as of why `Device58` last entry wasnt counted just like `Device00` last entry. btw, you can use [`lead()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/lead-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) to get the next query' entry column value.

Comment: Device58, is not counted because it was active today (25/5). if Device58 is not active tomorrow, then it should be counted. Devices are only counted when there is at least a calendar day between entry's in the data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT t2.device,
  CASE WHEN t2.starts > t2.stops THEN t2.stops ELSE t2.starts END
FROM
(
  SELECT device,
    COUNT(CASE WHEN t.prev IS null OR t.prev > 1 THEN 1 ELSE null END) AS starts,
    COUNT(CASE WHEN t.next IS null OR t.next > 1 THEN 1 ELSE null END) AS stops
  FROM
  (
    SELECT *,
     DATEDIFF(day, LAG(timestamp) OVER(PARTITION BY device ORDER BY timestamp), timestamp)
     AS prev,
     DATEDIFF(day, timestamp, LEAD(timestamp) OVER(PARTITION BY device ORDER BY timestamp))
     AS next
    FROM tbl
  ) AS t
  WHERE timestamp <= DATEADD(day, -1, GETDATE())
  GROUP BY device
) AS t2;
```

The core idea of the query is utilizing "window function" [`LAG()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/lag-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) and [`LEAD()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/lead-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) which introduced in SQL Server 2012. Both function allows for queries to be aware to what comes before and after of the current row.

Comment: You don't need cast `DATEDIFF` to integer, it is that anyway. Also shouldn't it be `...OR t.prev > 1 THEN 1...`?

Comment: @Charlieface you are right, kinda forgot those - i should add dummy data with more than 2 days of stop-start pairs - and i could remove some unnecessary parts. thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Requires at least SQL Server 2012. In earlier versions you could do it with a cursor, I guess. The `@Device` variable stores the list of devices, `@Log` is your sample data. By default the result set shows aggregates for the last month, but if you want to see more - change the `@Months` variable.

```
DECLARE @Log TABLE ([Device] VARCHAR(50), [TimeStamp] DATE)
DECLARE @Device TABLE ([Device] VARCHAR(50))

--=========================================
--START OF TEST DATA
INSERT INTO @Log VALUES ('Device00', '2022-04-25'), ('Device00', '2022-04-26'), ('Device00', '2022-04-27'), ('Device00', '2022-04-28'), ('Device00', '2022-04-29'), ('Device00', '2022-04-30'), ('Device00', '2022-05-01'), ('Device00', '2022-05-02'), ('Device00', '2022-05-03'), ('Device00', '2022-05-04'), ('Device00', '2022-05-05'), ('Device00', '2022-05-06'), ('Device00', '2022-05-07'), ('Device00', '2022-05-08'), ('Device00', '2022-05-09'), ('Device00', '2022-05-11'), ('Device00', '2022-05-12'), ('Device00', '2022-05-14'), ('Device00', '2022-05-15'), ('Device00', '2022-05-16'), ('Device00', '2022-05-17'), ('Device00', '2022-05-18'), ('Device00', '2022-05-19'), ('Device58', '2022-04-25'), ('Device58', '2022-04-26'), ('Device58', '2022-04-27'), ('Device58', '2022-04-28'), ('Device58', '2022-04-29'), ('Device58', '2022-04-30'), ('Device58', '2022-05-01'), ('Device58', '2022-05-02'), ('Device58', '2022-05-03'), ('Device58', '2022-05-04'), ('Device58', '2022-05-05'), ('Device58', '2022-05-06'), ('Device58', '2022-05-07'), ('Device58', '2022-05-08'), ('Device58', '2022-05-09'), ('Device58', '2022-05-11'), ('Device58', '2022-05-12'), ('Device58', '2022-05-14'), ('Device58', '2022-05-15'), ('Device58', '2022-05-16'), ('Device58', '2022-05-17'), ('Device58', '2022-05-18'), ('Device58', '2022-05-19'), ('Device58', '2022-05-20'), ('Device58', '2022-05-21'), ('Device58', '2022-05-22'), ('Device58', '2022-05-23'), ('Device58', '2022-05-24'), ('Device58', '2022-05-25')

INSERT INTO @Device VALUES ('Device00'), ('Device58')
--END OF TEST DATA
--=========================================

DECLARE @Months INT = 1
DECLARE @Today DATE = GETDATE()
DECLARE @EarliestDate DATE = DATEADD(M, -@Months, @Today)

; WITH CTE
AS
(
    SELECT @Today AS [Date]
    UNION ALL
    SELECT DATEADD(D, -1, [Date])
    FROM CTE WHERE [Date] > @EarliestDate
)

SELECT [Device], COUNT([Starts]) AS [Starts], COUNT([Stops]) AS [Stops] FROM
(
SELECT
    [DeviceDates].[Device],
    CASE 
        WHEN
            (
                LEAD([Log].[TimeStamp], 1) OVER (ORDER BY [DeviceDates].[Device], [DeviceDates].[Date]) IS NOT NULL
                AND [Log].[TimeStamp] IS NULL
            )
        OR
            (
                ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY [DeviceDates].[Device] ORDER BY [DeviceDates].[Date]) = 1
                AND [Log].[TimeStamp] IS NOT NULL
            )
        THEN 1
    END [Starts],
    CASE 
        WHEN [DeviceDates].[Date] != @Today
        AND [Log].[TimeStamp] IS NOT NULL
        AND LEAD([Log].[TimeStamp], 1) OVER (ORDER BY [DeviceDates].[Device], [DeviceDates].[Date]) IS NULL
        THEN 1
    END [Stops]
FROM (
    SELECT Device, [Date] 
    FROM CTE
    CROSS JOIN @Device
) AS [DeviceDates]
LEFT OUTER JOIN @Log AS [Log]
    ON [DeviceDates].[Device] = [Log].[Device]
    AND [DeviceDates].[Date] = [Log].[TimeStamp]
) aggregated
GROUP BY [Device]
```

Comment: @JGaard Did it work for you?

Answer (score 0):

```
with data as (
    select *,
        datediff(day, cast('20000101' as date), "TimeStamp")
          - row_number() over (partition by Device order by "TimeStamp") as grp
    from T
)
select distinct Device, count(*) over (partition by Device) as "Count"
from data
group by Device, grp
-- eliminate anything that still on a streak through yesterday
having max(Timestamp) < dateadd(day, -1, cast(getdate() as date));
```

Uses standard gaps and islands numbering. It does rely on `row_number()` so it will work on 2005 editions and later.

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2014&fiddle=b1698ddc0350c3087a3fdaf9554c54ad

Comment: I have testet @puszczyk's method. I'll need to test the others too. There seams to be an odd glitch some where in my data, and I'll be looking into that too, during the weekend.